# Google Docs / Apps Script: Insert text with styles

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm looking into inserting a simple text block to a Google Doc, using the [Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview). It looks like it's possible to select a range of text and apply styles to it, an example is presented in this question and answer: [Formatting text with apps script (Google Docs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830539/formatting-text-with-apps-script-google-docs) / but this doesn't cover **inserting the text with the styles** .

Following the example [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/docs/quickstart/translate) - I've edited the insertText method to simply insert a text and format it like below, which hasn't worked the way it's supposed to. It's inserting the text but without the styles.

```
function insertText(newText) {
       var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
       cursor.insertText(newText).setForegroundColor('#123123').setBackgroundColor('#000').setItalic(true);
}
```

Ideally I'm looking for a way to insert the text with the styling, something like below:

```
/// props being something on the lines of 
/// { bold: true, fontFamily: 'something', italic: true, backgroundColor, foregroundColor etc... }

...insertText(text, {props});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to set the text style when the text is inserted using Google Apps Script.
- You want to set the text style with `{ bold: true, fontFamily: 'something', italic: true, backgroundColor, foregroundColor etc... }`.

In this case, I think that `setAttributes` can be used for achieving your goal.

#### Sample script:

```
function insertText(newText) {
  var prop = {"BOLD": true, "FONT_FAMILY": "Arial", "ITALIC": true, "BACKGROUND_COLOR": "#ffff00", "FOREGROUND_COLOR": "#ff0000"};

  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  var text = cursor.insertText(newText);
  var attributes = Object.entries(prop).reduce((o, [k, v]) => Object.assign(o, {[k]: v}), {});
  text.setAttributes(attributes);
}
```

- The keys like "BOLD", "FONT_FAMILY" and so on can be seen at the official document. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute) From this document, you can select other styles.

#### References:

- [setAttributes(attributes)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setattributesattributes)
- [Enum Attribute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute)

Comment: OP says `cursor.insertText(newText).setForegroundColor('#123123').setBackgroundColor('#000').setItalic(true);` this didn't work. Any reason?

Comment: @TheMaster I think that the script works. From `which hasn't worked the way it's supposed to.` I thought that OP might have tested to use the object. From OP's direction which wants to set the text style using the object like `{ bold: true, fontFamily: 'something', italic: true, backgroundColor, foregroundColor etc... }`, I proposed to use `setAttributes`. If this alsy didn't work, I think that the reason might be the same with the 1st issue. At that time, I will confirm it.